# Beautiful Soup find() isn't finding all results for Class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have code trying to pull all the html stuff within the tracklist container, which should have 88 songs. The information is definitely there (I printed the soup to check), so I'm not sure why everything after the first 30 `react-contextmenu-wrapper` are lost.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re


spotify = 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3vSFv2hZICtgyBYYK6zqrP'
html = urlopen(spotify)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

main = soup.find(class_ = 'tracklist-container')
print(main)
```

Thank you for the help.
Current output from printing is as follows:

```
                  1.
              </div></div><div class="tracklist-col name"><div class="top-align track-name-wrapper"><span class="track-name" dir="auto">Move On - Teen Daze Remix</span><span class="artists-albums"><a href="/artist/3HrczLBDJXJu6dJWEMbKHa" tabindex="-1"><span dir="auto">Garden City Movement</span></a>     • <a href="/album/4p8FxnuYzykCcN7xbjA9jq" tabindex="-1"><span dir="auto">Entertainment</span></a></span></div></div><div class="tracklist-col explicit"></div><div class="tracklist-col duration"><div class="top-align"><span class="total-duration">5:11</span><span class="preview-duration">0:30</span></div></div><div class="progress-bar-outer"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div></li><li class="tracklist-row js-track-row tracklist-row--track track-has-preview" data-position="2" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="tracklist-col position-outer"><div class="play-pause top-align"><svg aria-label="Play" class="svg-play" role="button"><use xlink:href="#icon-play" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use></svg><svg aria-label="Pause" class="svg-pause" role="button"><use xlink:href="#icon-pause" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use></svg></div><div class="tracklist-col__track-number position top-align">
                  2.
              </div></div><div class="tracklist-col name"><div class="top-align track-name-wrapper"><span class="track-name" dir="auto">Flicker</span><span class="artists-albums"><a href="/artist/4qpWUfUAeI34HzvCORn1ze" tabindex="-1"><span dir="auto">Forhill</span></a>     • <a href="/album/0gfz1Tbst40swwL357cRqG" tabindex="-1"><span dir="auto">Flicker</span></a></span></div></div><div class="tracklist-col explicit"></div><div class="tracklist-col duration"><div class="top-align"><span class="total-duration">3:45</span><span class="preview-duration">0:30</span></div></div><div class="progress-bar-outer"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div></li><li class="tracklist-row js-track-row tracklist-row--track track-has-preview" data-position="3" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="tracklist-col position-outer"><div class="play-pause top-align"><svg aria-label="Play" class="svg-play" role="button"><use xlink:href="#icon-play" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use></svg><svg aria-label="Pause" class="svg-pause" role="button"><use xlink:href="#icon-pause" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></use></svg></div><div class="tracklist-col__track-number position top-align">
```

...

```
                  30.
              </div></div><div class="tracklist-col name"><div class="top-align track-name-wrapper"><span class="track-name" dir="auto">Trapdoor</span><span class="artists-albums"><a href="/artist/3nqTFzjmi1LLM6pn0TRMv8" tabindex="-1"><span dir="auto">Eagle Eyed Tiger</span></a>     • <a href="/album/48Q8Jgk1x4wiHWecV4nlz6" tabindex="-1"><span dir="auto">Future or Past</span></a></span></div></div><div class="tracklist-col explicit"></div><div class="tracklist-col duration"><div class="top-align"><span class="total-duration">4:14</span><span class="preview-duration">0:30</span></div></div><div class="progress-bar-outer"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div></li></ol><button class="link js-action-button" data-track-type="view-all-button">View all on Spotify</button></div>
```

Last entry *should* be the 88th. It just feels like my search results got truncated.

Comment: Current output? Expected output? Things you have tried?

Comment: Checking `print(soup)` I can only find 30 entries in the whole original HTML code, even outside the 'tracklist-container' tag.

Comment: @BurningKarl you're right, I just checked it again. There are 30 entries at the beginning. I was glancing through and saw a big block of...stuff at the end and saw all the songs in there. I noticed in the 30th entry `<button class="link js-action-button" data-track-type="view-all-button">
        View all on Spotify
       </button>`. I'm not sure if something about how the website is set up is preventing the script from accessing more than 30 songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all there in the response just within a **script** tag.

You can see the start of the relevant javascript object here:

[image]

I would regex out the required string and parse with json library.

---

**Py:**

```
import requests, re, json

r = s.get('https://open.spotify.com/playlist/3vSFv2hZICtgyBYYK6zqrP')
p = re.compile(r'Spotify\.Entity = (.*?);')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
print(len(data['tracks']['items']))
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to extract the information from the javascript object by going down all the nested dicts!

Answer (score 1):

Since it seemed you were on right track, I did not try to solve the full problem and rather tried to provide you a hint which could be helpful: **Do dynamic webscraping**.

"**Why Selenium? Isn’t Beautiful Soup enough?**

Web scraping with Python often requires no more than the use of the Beautiful Soup to reach the goal. Beautiful Soup is a very powerful library that makes web scraping by traversing the DOM (document object model) easier to implement. But it does only static scraping. Static scraping ignores JavaScript. It fetches web pages from the server without the help of a browser. You get exactly what you see in “view page source”, and then you slice and dice it. If the data you are looking for is available in “view page source” only, you don’t need to go any further. But if you need data that are present in components which get rendered on clicking JavaScript links, dynamic scraping comes to the rescue. The combination of Beautiful Soup and Selenium will do the job of dynamic scraping. Selenium automates web browser interaction from python. Hence the data rendered by JavaScript links can be made available by automating the button clicks with Selenium and then can be extracted by Beautiful Soup."
https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25

Here is what I see at the end of the 30 songs in the DOM which refers to a button:

```
    </li>
   </ol>
   <button class="link js-action-button" data-track-type="view-all-button">
    View all on Spotify
   </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I will try to see how I can interact with this button. I've used selenium a little bit. What I'm curious about is that I can't find that code when I use inspect element on the webpage, or maybe I'm not searching for it correctly?

Comment: I wrote the result of soup.prettify() into a file. Above portion of the DOM is taken from that file.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing

```
main = soup.find(class_ = 'tracklist-container')
```

the class "tracklist-container" only holds these 30 items,
i'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want
what's afterwards try parsing the class afterwards.

in other words, the class contains 30 songs, i visited the site and found 30 songs so it might be only for logged in users.